# How to get TActionMainMenuBar drop down items to scroll when there are too many items to show

Tags: delphi, menu, taction, tactionmanager

Does anyone know how to get a TActionMainMenuBar with TThemedPopupMenu to act like the standard menus, in that if there is too many items to fit on the screen (vertically), two scroll buttons appear (one top, one bottom)?

I have tried:

- Setting TActionMainMenuBar.Orientation to boTopToBottom and TActionMainMenuBar.AllowScrolling to true - This makes the bar on the form to have scroll bars and you can't actually see the top items.

It sort of looks like this:

```
+---------------------+
|         ^           |
|         v           |
+---------------------+
```

Instead of something like this:

```
+---------------------+
|        File         |
+---------------------+
```

- Setting TThemedPopupMenu.Orientation to boTopToBottom and TThemedPopupMenu.AllowScrolling to true. This has the effect of squishing the dropping down menu horizontally, with icons and short cuts drawn on top of each other.

The reason for setting these properties is because TCustomActionDockBar.SetAllowScrolling is only set to true when "AllowScrolling and (Orientation = boTopToBottom))"

The only reference on the Internet I have found about this type of thing is Brian Long's "[Actions, Action Lists And Action Managers](http://www.blong.com/Articles/Actions/Actions.htm#ActionBands)"

Does anyone know if it is possible to get Action Managers to scroll vertically? or are there any references that might help me out?﻿

Comment: Presumably there's no scrolling because it's a 100% pure VCL component and Emba never added support for scrolling.

Comment: TRibbonStyleMainPopupMenu set AllowScrolling to true and TCustomActionPopupMenu (which TRibbonStyleMainPopupMenu inherits from) sets the Orientation to boTopToBottom, so there must be some scrolling support implemented.